# ionic inAppBrowser scroll not working on ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, inappbrowser

I try to integrate a webpage in my app with ionic InAppBrowser.
It seam work correctly but, on iOS, it's impossible to scroll with on finger. (it work if you try to scroll with two fingers).

my app.component code :

```js
constructor(private platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, private splashScreen: SplashScreen, private network: Network, private iab: InAppBrowser) {
   platform.ready().then(() => {
     this.networkCheck();
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
       var browser = this.iab.create("https://agenceho5.com", "_self", { location: 'no', zoom: 'no', hideurlbar: 'yes', toolbar: 'no' });
       browser.show()
       splashScreen.hide();
     });
   });
 }
```

I've also tried to replace inAppBrowser by iframe, but, always on iOS, my iframe width is equal to 300000px so embed web page not apear as expected and the scroll problem seam to be the same than with inAppBrowser ...

my iframe code :

```html
<div style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch">
    <iframe style="width:100%;height:600px" src="www.iframe.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

My question seam basic but i can't resolve it : **How can I embed a webpage in Ionic** (working in iOS) ???